# Open link in same window with WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a Win application form with a `WebBrowser` control. I load a URL (for example: sign in of google.com) and after signing in, there is a button to download a file.

When I click on the download Button on the page in the `WebBrowser`, the address is sent to an external browser, and therefore the outside browser will request username and password again (which is not Ok).

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Lets start by you posting `what you have tried and where you are stuck`

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the NewWindow3 event.  In your event handler cancel it, then redirect the webbrowser control to the URL it was trying to open.

Like,

```
(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser).NewWindow3 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(Browser_NewWindow3);

private void Browser_NewWindow3(ref object browserObj, ref bool cancel, uint dwFlags, string openerURL, string targetURL)
    {
        cancel = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(targetURL);
    }
```